# How can I get the "This PC" Icon to show on the Desktop?

Tags: windows, desktop

How can I persuade Windows Server 2012 onwards to put the "This PC" icon on the Desktop?

In Server 2008 it could be achieved through right-clicking the "Computer" icon in the Start Menu, or it can be done in the Control Panel through *Personalisation* -> *Desktop Icons*, if available.

But Personalisation requires the Desktop Experience feature to be installed in Windows Server editions, and the "This PC" tile on the Start Screen doesn't offer the *Show on Desktop* option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even in newer versions of Windows (including Windows 11 at time of writing), the old Desktop Icon Settings dialog is still available, and can be accessed through running `desk.cpl 0,5` .

[image: Run desk.cpl 0,5]

This makes it possible to add back the usual array of Desktop icons, including This PC, the user's profile folder, etc.

[image: Desktop Icon Settings]

An alternative route to the same dialog is available through:

```
rundll32 shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,0
```

To really save on keystrokes, [TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6942-add-remove-default-desktop-icons-windows-10-a.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20like,4%20below%20instead.) suggests `desk.cpl ,5`, although note that PowerShell won't like the argument beginning with a comma.

Either option works for me, doing quick tests in 2012R1/R2, 2016 and 2022, and Windows 10/11.

---

Just a quick caveat: I've found that on some Server versions that if the wallpaper hasn't been changed from the default, this method may remove it and give you a black background.

See my other answer for a Registry-based method that avoids this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the classical way that exists since long before there were dialogs to show or hide desktop icons:

1. Create a new shortcut on the desktop
2. For the target, enter:

   ```
   explorer.exe shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
   ```
3. Give it any name you want, for example `This PC`
4. Click on `Finish`

You can easily place this on the default desktop for all users or deploy it with scripts or group policies.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the icons you want

- go to Add Rule or Feature
- press next without selecting anything till you get to the features
  dialog
- select 'Desktop Experience' feature and install it (you will find it
  under 'user interfaces and infrastructure' )
- restart your windows server
- after restart right click on your desktop and choose 'Personalize'
  then select 'Change desktop icons'
- add icons you want

---

Comment: The only real problem with this method is that it tends not to be convenient to restart an instance of Windows Server.

Comment: Also, you are adding the whole "Desktop Experience" feature, which includes several things you might not want on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the desk.cpl method can sometimes remove the default wallpaper if one was set.  So perhaps a slightly cleaner way to do this is with a Registry entry.  This can be run from the command prompt.

> `reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel  /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"  /t REG_DWORD  /d 0`

(If the value is missing or set to 1, the icon is "hidden".  A value of 0 means "not hidden".)

After doing this, the icon should show on the desktop after a refresh, e.g. with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

A second registry key (`ClassicStartMenu` instead of `NewStartPanel`) perhaps sets it for older versions of Windows or a different Explorer mode.  The desk.cpl method sets both values.

> `reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu  /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"  /t REG_DWORD  /d 0`

Both key names suggest to me that they're probably from Windows 8/2012 era or later.  I don't know if older versions of Windows use something different.